# Ldap server return result control?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, openldap

Hi I'm implementing an ldap query api. I would like to do it in such a way that I set a limit to 10 (say). I need ldap to return the first 10 values with a continuation-context-parameter that can be used to continue to return the next 10 results with a new query(with continuation-context-parameter passed as argument). Is this possible in ldap server?

Im trying to implement the api in java. I know that the SearchControl's setCountLimit() method can be used to set the number of elements but Im not able to find any methods that allow the results to be returned from where is originally left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [PagedResultsControl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/PagedResultsControl.html).

For more sophistication you can use the `VirtualListViewControl` available in the JNDI LDAP Booster Back, if you can find it. For this, with OpenLDAP you need to install and configure the `sssvlv` overlay.